# TP-Link TL-WN821N v4 won't connect to my Wireless

Tags: wireless, 13.04

I've bought a TP-Link TL-WN821N special for Ubuntu, I was advised that it would work, but it doesn't.
When I plug in the receiver Ubuntu does recognize and I can choose between the networks available. When I type in the password it tries to connect, but after a short time it asks for my password again!

This is the first time I've ever used Ubuntu and I'm a noob with things like coding :(

I have V4 of the receiver, which is the latest version. And I'm running stable 13.04.

**I can connect to my Android portable hotspot though**, but I'm sure I've entered the correct password to my home WiFi

Regards,
Joran

Comment: plug in the usb , then connect to wireless ... if it ask for password again open terminal and type this > sudo service network-manager restart, and reconnect again

Comment: It doesn't work :(
But I've come a little bit further, when I set a portable hotspot on my android phone it can connect...
The password for my home network is correct though

Comment: update your question with these details ...